# Uncaught ReferenceError: output is not defined when using jQuery $.post() in file file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, .post

I have a dynamic search which uses jQuery and a PHP search file to dynamically show the results below. I just changed my log in scripts and sessions; now i am having issues with a search bar that searches through the members in a DB. When I was going through the testing I see that on each keyUp the jQuery function runs properly but there is some sort of issue inside of my search.php file. It seems like there is no $userCount or $userCount = 0 because it will display "There Were No Search Results"which only happens when it equals $userCount== 0

Here are the parts of my index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function searchUserQ(){
            var searchTxt = $("input[name='userSearch']").val();
            if (searchTxt == '') {

                // $.post("includes/search.php", {searchVal:searchTxt},
                //  function(output){
                //      $("#userResults").html(output);
                //  });
            }else{
                $.post("includes/search.php", {searchVal:searchTxt},
                    function(output){
                        $("#userResults").html(output);
                    }); 
                console.log(output);
            }
        }
    </script>

<form class="editUser" action="index.php" method="post">
    <h1>Search For Employee</h1>
    <input type="text" name="userSearch" id="userSearch" placeholder="Search For Employee By First Or Last Name | Press Space To View All Employees" onkeyup="searchUserQ();" />
    <submit type="submit" />
    div id="userResults">

    </div>
</form>
```

and here is my search.php file

```
<?php
    // this file connects to the database
    include("connect.inc.php");

    if(isset($_POST['searchVal'])){
        // turn that the user searched into a varible
        $searchQ = $_POST['searchVal'];
        // delete any symbols for security
        $searchQ = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i", "", $searchQ);
        $output      = "";

        // Search through these columns inside the main database
        $userSearchQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dealerEmployees WHERE 
            firstName   LIKE '%$searchQ%'  or 
            lastName    LIKE '%$searchQ%'
        ");

        // count the number of results
        $userCount = mysql_num_rows($userSearchQuery);
        if($userCount == 0){
            // $output = "There Were No Search Results";
        }else{
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($userSearchQuery)){
                // define dynamic varibles for each loop iteration
                $id         = $row['id'];
                $firstName  = $row['firstName'];
                $lastName   = $row['lastName'];
                $address    = $row['address'];
                $phone      = $row['phone'];
                $email      = $row['email'];
                $passwordQ   = $row['password'];
                $permission = $row['permission'];
                $photo      = "images/" . $row['profilePhoto'];

                $output .= "<li><div class='employeeSearch' style=\"background: url('$photo'); width: 75px; height: 75px\"></div><h6>" . $firstName  . "</h6>" . " " .  "<h6>" . $lastName . "</h6><a href='#' class='employee' data-firstName='$firstName' data-lastName='$lastName' data-address='$address' data-phone='$phone' data-email='$email' data-password='$passwordQ' data-permission='$permission' data-id='$id'>Select Employee</a></li>";
            }
        }
    }

    echo $output;
```

Any suggestions why this is happening?

Comment: The `output` variable is local to the callback function. Your `console.log()` call is not inside that.

Comment: You're also doing the `console.log()` right after you send the AJAX call, not waiting for it to finish.

Comment: Since the output is an `<li>`, shouldn't `userResults` be a `<ul>`, not `<div>`?

Comment: Put the SQL in a string, and when `$userCount` is 0 do `$output = $sql;` so you can see the query that was performed. Then try it by hand and see what it returns.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error in the title is that you have `console.log(output)` outside the callback function. This has two problems: First, the variable `output` is not in scope; second, it runs immediately, not after the AJAX call returns. Move it into the callback:

```
function searchUserQ(){
    var searchTxt = $("input[name='userSearch']").val();
    if (searchTxt != '') {
        $.post("includes/search.php", {searchVal:searchTxt},
            function(output){
                console.log(output);
                $("#userResults").html(output);
        });  
    }
}
```